# How to compute the likelihood's Jacobian of a bootstrapped spatial autoregressive specification?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bootstrap, spatial

Say one has the following [data generating process (DGP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_generating_process) *(known as the SAR ou spatial lag model in the literature)*:

$\boldsymbol{y} = \rho \boldsymbol{W}y + \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{u}$

where $\boldsymbol{y}$ is a $n \times 1$ endogenous vector, $\boldsymbol{X}$ an exogenous $n \times k$ matrix, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ a $k \times 1$ vector of coefficients, $\boldsymbol{W}$ a $n \times n$ spatial lag operator, $\rho$ a scalar coefficient of autoregression and $\boldsymbol{u}$ a vector of errors, wished iid normal.

Impossible to use OLS because of endogeneity concerns, and there is a need for a simultaneous estimation technic: let's use an MLE. Explicitly

$\left(\boldsymbol{I} - \rho\boldsymbol{W}\right) \boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{S}(\rho) \boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{y}_{S_{\rho}} = \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{u} \iff \boldsymbol{u} = \boldsymbol{y}_{S_{\rho}} - \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}$.

where $\boldsymbol{\beta} = \left(\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{X} \right)^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{y}_{S_{\rho}} $ (whence the need for a simultaneous estimation technic)

Which yields the following (concentrated on $\rho$) likelihood:
$$
\mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{\rho})=
  \left(\frac{2\pi e}{n}\boldsymbol{u}^{'}\boldsymbol{u}\right)^{-\frac{n}{2}}
  \begin{vmatrix} \boldsymbol{S}\left(\rho\right) \end{vmatrix}
$$

and I want $\hat{\rho} = \max_{\rho} \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{\rho})$

---

Ok. So ***from now*** starts my question. Say I want to [(block) bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Block_bootstrap) estimate $\hat{\rho}$. Let's denote the bootstrapping resampling process by an operator, say, $\mathcal{B}(.)$ and then simply replace $\boldsymbol{y}_{S_{\rho}}$ by $\mathcal{B}(\boldsymbol{y}_{S_{\rho}})$, and $\boldsymbol{X}$ by $\mathcal{B}(\boldsymbol{X})$ everywhere. Right ?

How would you do to compute the jacobian $\begin{vmatrix} \boldsymbol{S}\left(\rho\right) \end{vmatrix}$ ? Since working with $\mathcal{B}(\boldsymbol{S}_{\rho})$ would make no sense.

---

A python toy-example

```
import numpy as np
from random import random as rd

S = np.array([[1.  ,rd(),rd(),rd()],
              [rd(),1.  ,rd(),rd()],
              [rd(),rd(),1.  ,rd()],
              [rd(),rd(),rd(),1.]])

y = np.array([[rd()],[rd()],[rd()],[rd()]])
bt = [0,1,1,2]#block bootstrapped (partial) overlapping

Bsy = np.dot(S,y)[bt]
```

---

#### Update

I may have found a solution, and only for non-overlapping sub-samples ($S$ invertible/full rank):

One has $\boldsymbol{Z}\boldsymbol{y}=\mathcal{B}(\boldsymbol{y}_{S_{\rho}})$ for $\boldsymbol{Z}=\mathcal{B}( \ \ \mathcal{B}( \ \ \mathcal{B}(S_{\rho})' \ \ )'^{-1} \ \ )^{-1}$.

```
Z = np.linalg.inv(np.linalg.inv(S[bt].T[bt].T)[bt])
```

---

Any tricks to make this less extensive in term of computation ? A first one would be:

1. Knowing that  $\det(\mathbf{A^{-1}}) = \frac{1}{\mathbf{\det(A)}}$; there is no need to [compute the last matrix inversion](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/), taking $\frac{1}{\begin{vmatrix}\boldsymbol{Z}^{-1}(\rho)\end{vmatrix}}$ is ok.
2. ...

Comment: Can you clarify to readers what you mean by "DGP"?